# Show hide javascript cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

```
function showhide() {
if( document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display=='none' ){
  document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display = 'table-row'; // set to table-row instead of an empty string
}else{
  document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display = 'none';
}
}
```

I have this working javascript function to hide a row in a table - like this

```
<tr id="hidethis" style="display:table-row;">
```

It works fine but i want to use cookies to remember which option user chose. I cant figure out how to properly set cookies, some advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to remember it permanently go with `localStorage` else you can go with `sessionStorage`. These are `html5` browser functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> You need to store the value in `cookies` and read those values on [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)  event ad set your `style` accordingly

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie) used to create and read cookies values

```js
var createCookie = function(name, value, days) {
  var expires;
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
  } else {
    expires = "";
  }
  document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
};

function getCookie(c_name) {
  if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
    c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    if (c_start != -1) {
      c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
      c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
      if (c_end == -1) {
        c_end = document.cookie.length;
      }
      return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
    }
  }
  return "";
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var cookieVal = getCookie('display');
  if (cookieVal) {
    document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display = cookieVal;
  }
});

function showhide() {
  if (document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display == 'none') {
    document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display = 'table-row'; // set to table-row instead of an empty string
    createCookie('display', 'table-row', 365);
  } else {
    document.getElementById("hidethis").style.display = 'none';
    createCookie('display', 'none', 365);
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="hidethis" style="display:table-row;">
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems to be working. I understand this correctly, will this store a cookie for a year?

Comment: Yes it will! **Happy coding!**